# How can I keep my disabled controls opaque?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I've noticed that when I disable controls (`controlName.enabled := false;`) that they automatically become translucent.

Is there a way I can force them to stay opaque?

I've tried `controlName.Opacity := 1;` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I've also tried embedding the control in a TLayout and then disabling the TLayout, but the translucency seems to be picked up by the embedded control.

[EDIT]

Here's an example of what I'm seeing In this case it's covering up a TLabel containing a big capitol F.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I think you would probably need to search in the Firemonkey source code to find out how disabling affects painting, to override it.

Comment: The short story is I have a TSplitter on a form. The grip does not show up on Android or iOS. To indicate that the TSplitter is there to the user. I've added a rectangle as a child of it, and then set its colour (there appears to be no way to colour a TSplitter directly).Once I add the rectangle to the TSplitter, it no longer works (the TRectangle intercepts the click for some gawd unknown reason). Disabling the TRectangle allows the TSplitter to work again; however, as I slide the splitter up (or left depending on how you've oriented it) you can see ghosts of the controls you're sliding over.

Comment: Translucent? Really? You can see what's behind them?

Comment: I think you can change the skins in firemonkey and maybe you just need to make your OWN TSplitter subcontrol and add your painting of a grabber to it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes indeed. Check out the screen shot I added. This happens on Win32, Android, and iOS (I haven't had a need to test on anything else at this point).

Comment: Did you mean `Enabled` rather than `Enable`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes indeed.

Comment: Maybe the problem here is that Firemonkey doesn't implement any z-order clipping, unlike the VCL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `DisabledOpacity` to 1.

See example with two buttons added to a form :

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.DisabledOpacity := 1;
  Button1.Enabled := not Button1.Enabled;
end;
```

This is a protected member so you have to override the control in your code.

```
 TButton = class(FMX.Stdctrls.TButton)
 //
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

Comment: Can you expose private member with an inter-poser class?

Comment: Technically it is protected so I changed that in the answer.

Comment: This works as well, but I did it with a `TMyRectangle = class(TRectangle);` and `TMyRectangle(Rectangle1).DisabledOpacity := 1;` combo (Protected Hack / THack) rather than spinning off another procedure to set the value.

Answer (score 5):

Set your control(TRectangle) to `hittest := false;`

It will no longer catch mouse events and the parent control will.
For other controls you can combine it with `Tabstop:=false`. Now it will not get focus so most functionality wil be disabled.

Comment: +1 This is an easier solution for my specific situation. The other answer better answers my original question so got the check mark. Thanks for giving me both.

Answer (score 1):

DisabledOpacity is a private property of TControl, you can find it in FMX.Controls.TControl.

You can create a custom class of tcontrol where DisabledOpacity is public and set it to your controls like (to every TControl descendant):

```
  TmyC = class(TControl)
  public
    property DisabledOpacity;
  end;

...

  TmyC(Button1).DisabledOpacity := 1;
```